# how to arrange a linear line according to the data points

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a 2D data set. Y axis goes from 5 to -200, and X axis goes from 0 to 100. I have slope and intercept values to draw a linear line between the data points. However, I am having some visual problems.

Here is how my data looks like when I plot them:
[image: https://imgur.com/]

Here is how my plot looks like when I draw the line.
[image]

The way I plot my line is:

```
axis.set_xlim([0,101])
x_vals = np.array(axis.get_xlim())
y_vals = intercept + slope * x_vals
plt.plot(x_vals, y_vals, c="black")
```

I'd like to preserve the first image and add the line on top of it. I was wondering if someone could help me out.

Comment: The very much looks like your `slope` is just wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong. It's just the y-limits changes due to the new line. To fix this, reset the y limites:

```
axis.set_xlim([0,101])
x_vals = np.array(axis.get_xlim())

# save the old y limits
y_lims = axis.get_ylim()

# these new y_vals are larger than the old y_lims
y_vals = intercept + slope * x_vals
axis.plot(x_vals, y_vals, c="black")

# reset y_limits
axis.set_ylims(y_lims)
```

Comment: Dude! you're a life saver. By the way, the last line should be ```axis.set_ylim(y_lims)```. Thanks!